# How can i implement a HCaptcha in Blazor-Server?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side, hcaptcha

I have been trying to implement a hCaptcha to my blazor-server project for the last couple days, but everything i tried failed in one way or another.

My most promising attempt was to just add the HTML-code from the hcaptcha website to the app.
I added

```
<script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer></script>
```

inside the <!head> element of the _Layout.cshtml, and

```
<div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="10000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000001"></div>
```

in my index.razor, to show the captcha there.
The odd thing is: Every time I load the site, the captcha is visible for about 0.2 seconds and then becomes invisible.
I also tried the same code in the w3schools.com HTML Simulator and it worked perfectly fine, so I assume this has something to do with blazor.

Here is my code
index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>Currently, the <code>ChildContext</code> is temporarily rendered by the week component, and the data-related operating components in all cells are not encapsulated and will be refined later</p>

<div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="10000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000001"></div>


@code {
    

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
    }

    void CheckValidity()
    {
        //GeneralMethods.CheckCaptcha();
    }
}
```

and _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace NixPfusch.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="NixPfusch.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Added Script for hCaptcha-->
    <script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer></script>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be apprechiated!